# multiple post parameter on a method (mvc, php)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, methods

I tried pass/throw multiple post param on this kind method :

```html
public function create()
    {
        BranchModel::createBranch(Request::post('fname, fsomething, fblabla')); 
        Redirect::to('branch');
    }
```

```html
public function create()
    {
        BranchModel::createBranch(Request::post('fname', 'fsomething', 'fblabla')); 
        Redirect::to('branch');
    }
```

But both turn to be wrong apparently 
How is the correct way to do that? 
I tried to find on php documentation, but couldn't get a relevant reference. 

 does anyone have a reference for this? 

 Thank you...

Comment: Are you using a framework? If not it's pretty much up to you to figure out what the correct way is. I'd normally expect a request::post to accept at least two params, an url (string) and and an array of params

Comment: I don't use specific php framework, the thing is when I tried to send only 1 param it works, but I just don't know how is it written, if I'd like to send more than 1 param.. do I need to use separate comma or something else?

Comment: Request instance should be passed in as a dependency, that is not a "model" and setting HTTP headers is a responsibility of the view instances

Comment: If you're not sure how it's written then just check. If you're using a proper IDE like PHPStorm, Netbeans or similar you can just CTRL-click the class name and it will take you to the implementation. If not you can just check the source for the class wherever you found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be my basic understanding of how multiple post request being written on a controller.

this is the solution I discovered :

```html
public function create()
    {
        BranchModel::createBranch(
            Request::post('something'), 
            Request::post('somevar'), 
            Request::post('fooos')
            ); 
        Redirect::to('branch');
    }
```

thanks for dragging me out of this. not sure if it's the only way to achieve it, but it works. 
 have a nice day you all ;)